# Sending dynamic arrays in MPI, C++

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

My task is to measure time of communication betweeen two processes.
I want to send 4,8,...,1000,...., 10000 bytes of data and measure time it takes to send and receive back the message.
So i figured out that i will send an array of shorts.

When i send array initialised like that:

```
mpi::communicator world;
short message[100000];
....
world.send(1,0, message);
```

time seems to be ok, and I can see a time difference between message[100000] and [1000]

But I want to allocate array dynamically like that:

```
short *message = new short[100000];
...
world.send(1,0, *message);
```

It seems like the second send is always sending the same amount of data no matter what size the array will be.

So my question is, how to send a dynamically allocated array?

Comment: it's mpi::communicator world;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second case `message` is of type `short *` and `*message` dereferences to a scalar `short`, i.e. to the first element of the array only. Use

```
world.send(1, 0, message, n);
```

instead and vary the value of `n`. It should also (probably) work if you cast the pointer to a pointer to an array and then dereference it:

```
world.send(1, 0, *reinterpret_cast<int(*)[100]>(message));
```

The `int(*)[100]` type is a pointer to an integer array with 100 elements.